# How to run my Ruby programs without installing 20,000 file?

Tags: ruby, execute

I have written quite a few Ruby programs, but if I need to show my friend one of the program, I need to install Ruby 1.8.6 on that computer, and that is 20,000 files.  For running of my Ruby programs, is there a way besides this?

Comment: First, where exactly are you getting the 20,000 number that you keep repeating? Second, you realize that the number of files doesn't necessarily mean much in terms of disc space used. The source folder for Ruby 1.9.1 is 122MB with 12,627 files. As a quick comparison, a folder in my music directory is 25MB larger, even if it only has 16 files in it.

Comment: It is a typical One-click installer of Ruby 1.8.6... (ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]) On my Win 7, 32 bit machine, it says there are 21,437 files, and 3008 folders.  Size is 75.5MB, and size on hard drive is 142MB (even a 6 byte file takes 4kb on hard drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into RubyScript2Exe?

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/

Comment: that's a good way. how about, what if i need to change a line and show him how the code behaves differently... and not to install all those 20,000 files?

Comment: Then take your laptop with you.  Or tell your friend to install Ruby before you get there.  

You expect to be able to alter code in a language on a machine that doesn't have the language installed?  What language have you ever worked with that leads you to believe that's a reasonable expectation?

Answer (score 1):

#### Put the files on a flash device

I think you only need to set `RUBYLIB` to point over to the dev...

Answer (score 1):

[CodePad](http://codepad.org) is neat. It lets you write quick demonstrative scripts, and run them.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are quite good, but really, it's an interpreted language.  You should always expect that using it incurs the installation cost of the runtime.  The one-click installer makes installation on windows pretty trivial.  OS X has it preinstalled.  Ubuntu let's you install it with a single `apt-get` command.  You make it sound like the installation is difficult but it really isn't.

Comment: I see, I was hoping that a Ruby program could be runnable by just installing one EXE or maybe 20, 30 files, instead of 20,000 files.  But of course if that's the way it is, then so be it!

Comment: Note: it's nowhere near 20,000.  :-P

Answer (score 1):

package your application into .jar and bundle jruby with it. you will get single JAR file at the end, which you can doubleclick to run on most OS/Desktops